# Manually rotate log4j log file

Tags: java, log4j

I need to rotate log4j log file from inside of my program on a special event. Is it possible to do so? If yes, what is the best way of doing that? I need to have DateTime stamp in this file name.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a custom rolling and trigger policy and configure that in your `XML` file. Here is a related question where someone has done just that - [log4j.xml configuration with <rollingPolicy> and <triggeringPolicy>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705957/log4j-xml-configuration-with-rollingpolicy-and-triggeringpolicy)

A [log4j accompaniment](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/) has APIs that can help you here.